# How to access HDF5 dataset with szip compression using h5py

Tags: python, dataset, compression, hdf5, h5py

As the title says, I need to know how to access the dataset of an HDF5 file that has szip compression using h5py.
This is the error I get:

> IOError: can't read data (Dataset: Read failed)

Does anyone have an idea of how to access this dataset using h5py?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What system are your using to read the HDF5 file?
the h5py docs say this about SZIP:

- UNIX: if supplied with HDF5.
- Windows: read-only

So, if you are on Linux, you may need to update your HDF5 installation to add SZIP compression. Reference here:

[Supported h5py compression/processing filters](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/faq.html?highlight=szip#what-compression-processing-filters-are-supported)

Comment: I'm using the command prompt from Ubuntu. I will see if there are any updates which can fix this.